# How to make text overflow set width div without dropping down?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is 100px wide. It is set to `overflow-x:hidden`.

I would expect this to accomplish what I want, keeping the text from dropping down if it exceeds the length of the container, and instead overflow the container and be invisible.

```css
.user_name {
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='user_name'>This is a test</div>
```

The text will just drop down instead of overflowing the right of the container and being invisible. How can I achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to your rules.

```css
.user_name {
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='user_name'>This is a test This is a test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` on the div to restrict it to only one line.

```css
.user_name {
  width: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='user_name'>This is a test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use white-space:nowrap to avoid wrapping of text

```
  .user_name {
      width: 100px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Codpen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JNOBRb

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {
white-space: nowrap; 
width: 12em; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: clip; 
border: 1px solid #000000;}

<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

Comment: While this code fragment may answer the OP's question, the answer would be more useful if you'd add an explanation. Note that code-only answers tend to be flagged for quality review, which may cause them to be deleted.